# Spring integration testing with Schedulers.elastic

Tags: spring, project-reactor, reactor

I have the following spring reactor code that does saving in DB through Schedulers.elastic(). However I see the elastic thread does not end / commit until 60 seconds elapses(its idle time). So my integration test are failing unless I wait for that time. Is there a better way to do this ? like using  Schedulers.immediate() for tests and elastic for actual deployment.

```
public void method() {
   Mono.just(student)
   .flatMap(student -> populateStudentDetails(student))
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic)
   .subscribe(studentRepository::save);
}
```

I am running my test as below

```
@SpringBootTest
public class TestClass {
   @Test
   void testMethod() {
        testClass.method();
        //assertForDatainDB
        //fails if immediately asserted
        //succeeds if asserted after 60s
   }
}
```

Comment: I believe you should be using the StepVerifier to test this effectively. 

https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/929/reactive-programming-with-reactor-3/StepVerifier

Comment: Awesome this is great. I added StepVerfier.withVirtualTime and the test passed.  Thank you so much.

Comment: I think we need not add thenAwait() for cases like this.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe do you want to put in this as answer ?

Comment: Feel free to post it yourself, I wasn't 100% sure that would work as effectively

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by Darren Forsythe, I had to include StepVerifier.withVirtualTime to get the test passing

```
StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(() -> Mono.fromRunnable(() -> testClass.method())
  .verifyComplete();
```